# Is it possible to reference variables passed as 'item' and use their elements when looping through a jinja template?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

When attempting to loop through variables in ansible, while building a jinja2 template, I can't seem to reference the elements within the variables after passing them.

I've tried several permutations and I'm at a loss, it's probably simple, but I can't see it.

The yaml in question:

```
---
- name: testing some crazyness
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    domdb:
      dom1:
        ip: something
        mail: somethingelse
      dom2:
        ip: somethingdifferent
        mail: somethingelsedifferent
  tasks:
  - name:
    template:
      src: test.j2
      dest: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ domdb }}"
```

The template:

```
{{ item.ip. }}
{{ item.mail }}
```

I'm expecting this to output two files:
dom1, containing:
something
somethingelse

and dom2, containing:
somethingdifferent
somethingelsedifferent

Answer (score 0):

`domdb` is a dictionary, not a list. If you try to iterate over a dictionary, you only iterate over the keys. So your task is equivalent to:

```
  - template:
      src: test.j2
      dest: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - dom1
      - dom2
```

Your attempt to use `item.ip` and `item.mail` in your task should result in an `AnsibleUndefinedVariable` error message. You probably want this:

```
---
- name: testing some crazyness
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    domdb:
      - name: dom1
        ip: something
        mail: somethingelse
      - name: dom2
        ip: somethingdifferent
        mail: somethingelsedifferent
  tasks:
    - name:
      template:
        src: test.j2
        dest: "{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ domdb }}"
```

In this example `domdb` is a list. You could alternatively do this instead:

```
---
- name: testing some crazyness
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    domdb:
      dom1:
        ip: something
        mail: somethingelse
      dom2:
        ip: somethingdifferent
        mail: somethingelsedifferent
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: test.j2
        dest: "{{ item.0 }}"
      loop: "{{ domdb.items()|list }}"
```

Here, `domdb` is once again a dictionary, but use the dictionary `.items()` method to produce a list of `(key, value)` tuples.

In both of the above examples, I've replaced the legacy `with_items` with the `loop`.

Comment: On the second one, I'm getting issues still pulling the info out apparently...

`failed: (item=(u'dom1', {u'ip': u'something', u'mail': u'somethingelse'})) => {"changed": false, "item": ["dom1", {"ip": "something", "mail": "somethingelse"}], "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'list object' has no attribute 'ip'"}
failed: (item=(u'dom2', {u'ip': u'somethingdifferent', u'mail': u'somethingelsedifferent'})) => {"changed": false, "item": ["dom2", {"ip": "somethingdifferent", "mail": "somethingelsedifferent"}], "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'list object' has no attribute 'ip'"}`

Comment: Ignore that, it's getting late, I got the second one to work but it looks weird:

`[u'dom2', {u'ip': u'somethingdifferent', u'mail': u'somethingelsedifferent'}]
dom2
{u'ip': u'somethingdifferent', u'mail': u'somethingelsedifferent'}`

Comment: NM, I got it, item.1 is the first dict in an array, this is actually super useful because now I can hopefully find a way to iterate over arrays!

Answer (score 0):

Use [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) to iterate the dictionary. For example

```
- name:
  template:
    src: test.j2
    dest: "{{ item.key }}"
  loop: "{{ domdb|dict2items }}"
```

The template:

```
{{ item.value.ip }}
{{ item.value.mail }}
```

Comment: What version of ansible does dict2items ship with?

Comment: [New in version 2.6.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter)